# redirect content and populate iframe

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, iframe

After extensive searching and experimentation I've come to the conclusion that my dilemma is quite unique, it's simple in theory however, I would not be surprised if I were told that this is not possible.

In brief:
I want to redirect a page, to another page on my site, but not only that, once redirected I want the content of that page to populate a targeted iframe of the page it's being redirected to.

For example:
The original link to be clicked goes to Mysite.com/page1.php...before the content of Mysite.com/page1.php populates, it redirects to Mysite.com/index.php,
THEN mysite.com/page1 loads within mysite.com/index in a targeted iframe.

To be more specific:
I have a wordpress site where I've stripped away the header/sidebar, when a link is visited to a single post or page, the end user is viewing the stripped down page that i want to appear in an iframe of my index page where I have customized links and buttons to correspond with tags, categories and likewise.

From what I gather at this point it's probably impossible but any kind of input would be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: This is the opposite of the frame-breaker code used in the past to ensure you aren't inside a frame. What you do is redirect to index.php. Using the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] you can see which page redirected to index.php. If it is a page on your website, you load it in the iframe. So, the original page doesn't load the iframe, index.php does..

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback! I understand what you mean however it's still a little greek to me, any example code i can play with would be greatly appreciated, as I am more adept to "playing by ear"...I dont exactly know these things by heart

Answer (score 0):

You could tell page1.php and index.php your exact intentions by sending query vars.

For example ... in your page1.php you redirect (however you wish) to index.php?show=page1.php

Then ... index.php picks up the query variable (checks that it is from a restricted list that you have created perhaps) and then displays the iframe but with another query variable to stop page1.php redirecting again. Something like page1.php?redirect=no

For example ...

At the top of index.php put:

```
$safe_list=array("page1.php","page2.php");
$show = (isset($_GET['show'])) ? $_GET['show'] : FALSE;

if (in_array($_GET['show'],$safe_list)) {
    print "<iframe src='" . $_GET['show'] . "?redirect=no'></iframe>";
}

print "hello I'm index.php";
// rest of index.php
```

At the top of page1.php (before anything is sent to client) put:

```
$redirect = (isset($_GET['redirect'])) ? $_GET['redirect'] : FALSE;

if ($redirect!=='no') {
    header("Location: index.php?show=page1.php");
    exit;
}

print "hello I'm page1.php";
// rest of page1.php proper
```

Comment: thanks so much actually i had a thought like that, and thought i would come back and append before I got any replies...So im wondering is there any java that i need to add to my php file in order for that to work? for example http://www.example.com/page1.php#specified-link

Comment: also, this specified content i would want to show in a targeted iframe of my index.php, in this case, my iframe is named 'mainstage', so any visuals you could give me would be of great help thanks again!

Comment: I just described how you could do it with PHP scripts. It wouldn't need any other scripting. Don't know how it would fit in exactly with your Wordpress files. Assume you have access to index.php and page1.php to change their PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use javascript and load only some part of your website inside your index page ? [Here an example with jquery load() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)

I don't think iframe is a good way to do this.

Furthermore the content of your page inside the iframe will not be visible by the search engines.